# Deserializing KnowledgePackage in Drools 5.5.0

Tags: java, drools

I'm getting an exception  when adding a Collection after read it from a file with readObject()

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method) 
    at org.drools.base.ClassObjectType.isAssignableFrom(ClassObjectType.java:180) 
    at org.drools.reteoo.builder.PatternBuilder.attachPattern(PatternBuilder.java:95) 
    at org.drools.reteoo.builder.PatternBuilder.build(PatternBuilder.java:80) 
    at org.drools.reteoo.builder.GroupElementBuilder$AndBuilder.build(GroupElementBuilder.java:112) 
    at org.drools.reteoo.builder.GroupElementBuilder.build(GroupElementBuilder.java:70) 
    at org.drools.reteoo.builder.ReteooRuleBuilder.addSubRule(ReteooRuleBuilder.java:161) 
    at org.drools.reteoo.builder.ReteooRuleBuilder.addRule(ReteooRuleBuilder.java:134) 
    at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooBuilder.addRule(ReteooBuilder.java:113) 
    at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooRuleBase.addRule(ReteooRuleBase.java:445) 
    at org.drools.common.AbstractRuleBase.addRule(AbstractRuleBase.java:952) 
    at org.drools.common.AbstractRuleBase.addPackages(AbstractRuleBase.java:629) 
    at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooRuleBase.addPackages(ReteooRuleBase.java:472)
    at org.drools.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.addKnowledgePackages(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:149) 
    at DroolsEmpresa.readKnowledgeBaseFromMemoryFile(DroolsEmpresa.java:304) 
    at ServidorMR.cargaInfoConocimiento(ServidorMR.java:483) 
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:127)
```

The code for serialize the object is

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( fileName ) ); 
out.writeObject( kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages()); 
out.close();
```

And the code for deserialize is

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream( new FileInputStream( fileName) ); 
Collection<KnowledgePackage> kpkgs = (Collection<KnowledgePackage>)in.readObject(); 
in.close(); 
kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase(); 
kbase.addKnowledgePackages( kpkgs );
```

I thought this error may be due to a rule, but if I run `kbase.addKnowledgePackages()` after reading the rules from drl file, there will be no exception.

My environment  is eclipse 3.7, java 7.0.21 y drools 5.5.0.

Best Regards.

**UPDATE 1**

Execute test with java 7.0.05 and 7.0.07: the error persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was due to a rule like this

```
...
when
    a: Concept(...)
    b: Concept(...)
    or b: Concept(...)
    and (eval(...) or eval(...))
then
...
```

And the solution put in parenthesis the first or.